# How to use ormlite with SQL Server and Mars?

Tags: c#, dapper, sql-server-mars, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack aficionados, hello!

We are legion (I hope so), so please help a brother out :)

I am trying to populate two collections with one SQL Server 2008 stored procedure call that return two resultsets.
I have "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in my connection string but I am still getting this error:

> 'r.NextResult()' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

Here is my code:

```
IList<ProjectMember> projectMembers = null;

IList<Project> projects = DbFactory.Run(dbCnx =>
{
     using (var dbCmd = dbCnx.CreateCommand())
     {
          dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          dbCmd.CommandText = "mySchema.myStoredProc";
          dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@categoryId", categoryId));

          using (profiler.Step("ProjectService.myStoredProc"))
          {
              var r = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
              projectMembers = r.ConvertToList<ProjectMember>();
              return r.NextResult() ? r.ConvertToList<Project>() : null;
          }
      }
 });
```

Is this possible? If so, can someone please show me an example on how to do that?

Thanks,

Samir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way but I had to replace ormLite with Dapper:

```
            using(var cnx = DbFactory.CreateConnection(Global.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var multi = cnx.QueryMultiple("mySchema.myStoredProc", new { communityId, categoryId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
                {
                    var projectMembers = multi.Read<ProjectMember>().ToList();
                    var projects = multi.Read<Project>().ToList();
                    BindProjectMembers(projects, projectMembers);

                    return projects;
                }
            }
```

It works perfectly and is twice as fast (from 40 ms to 20 ms) than before the MARS amelioration.

Comment: That's excellent! Would you mind explaining how you "Replace[d] ormLite with Dapper"?